# How can I keep blank before any data is entered?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use the following formula, but I would like to keep the cell blank until the data is entered. Any ideas on how I may go about it?

```
=IF((AND(E50="Yes",E51="Yes",E52="Yes")), "Yes, the effect is material", "No, the effect is not material")
```

Comment: Which cell is to be kept blank?

Comment: Hi! So I want to keep the formula cell blank until data is entered in all E50, E51, and E52.

Comment: `If(E50&E51&E52="", "", <your big long formula here>)` would probably suffice.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF((AND(E50="Yes",E51="Yes",E52="Yes")), "Yes, the effect is material", IF(OR(E50="",E51="",E52=""), "", "No, the effect is not material"))
```

Please vote if it was fixed for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use construct like below:

`=IF(COUNTBLANK(E50:E52)=3,"",IF(COUNTIF(E50:E52,"Yes")=3, "Yes, the effect is material", "No, the effect is not material"))`